# How to check if user is SignedIn in Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, navigation

Hy here everyone. I am new to flutter and i want to check if User is SignedIn. If so the user navigate to HomeScreen else SplashScreen.

Here is my main.dart

```
void main() async{
  runApp(MyApp());
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Instant Tasker',
      theme: theme(),
      initialRoute: SplashScreen.routeName,
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
```

Here is Splash Screen

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String routeName = "/splash";
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  startTime() async {
    var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 2);
    return new Timer(_duration, navigationPage);
  }

  void navigationPage() {
    var auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      } else {}
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTime();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Body()
    );
  }
}
```

However i achieved to check user at splash screen but it stays at splash screen to check user then move to HomeScreen which doesn't seems to be good.
Or can anybody suggest how to show CircularProgressIndicator instead of Splash Screen body when it is checking for user

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using `StreamProvder`

**Implementation**

**Steps**

Create a `CustomUser` Data model.

```
class CustomUser {
  final String userId;

  CustomUser({this.userId});
}
```

Create a class named `FirebaseAuthService` and create a `stream` to listen to Firebase `AuthStateChanges`

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class FirebaseAuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // create user obj based on firebase user
  CustomUser _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? CustomUser(userId: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth change user stream
  //Required stream
  Stream<CustomUser> get user {
    return auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }
}
}
```

Add a `StreamProvider` on top of the widget tree where you want to check for the **AuthState**.

```
void main() async{

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<CustomUser>.value(
        value: FirebaseAuthService().user,
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Instant Tasker',
          theme: theme(),
          initialRoute: SplashScreen.routeName,
          routes: routes,

        )
    );
  }
}
```

Create a `Wrapper` and return `SplashScreen` or `HomeScreen` based on AuthState.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<CustomUser>(context);

    if (user == null) {
      return SplashScreen();
    }

    return HomeScreen();
  }
}
```

Now you can use `final user = Provider.of<CustomUser>(context);`
in the widget tree to check if the user is null.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z05m8nlPRxk&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC&index=3

Comment: The following FirebaseException was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

The relevant error-causing widget was
MyApp
package:shop_app/main.dart:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      MethodChannelFirebase.app

Comment: try calling this `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();` before `runApp(MyApp());`

Comment: You're welcome. 
If this answer solved your issue, you may mark it as correct.